# How to sum duplicated values in SQL

Tags: mysql, data-extraction

The sum of the acquisition price of works of art for each year (for example, if there were two works of art purchased for $1500 and $1000  in 2007, and one work of art purchased for $500 in 2008, then the sums would be $2500 and $500, for 2007 and 2008 respectively).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table contains a field containing the year, and a field containing the price, you would simply use:

```
SELECT AcquisitionYear, SUM(Price) AS TotalPrice
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY AcquisitionYear
```

If your table contains a date field, you'd need to extract the year from this field using the YEAR() function:

```
SELECT YEAR(AcquisitionDate), SUM(Price) AS TotalPrice
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY YEAR(AcquisitionDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you're looking for is [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html).

So your query will look something like

```
SELECT YEAR(date), SUM(price)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY YEAR(date)
```